# Using UIKit and Bootstrap simultaneusly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, getuikit

Are there any known conflicts between [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/) and [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)?

Both with CSS and JS.